# Calling Java Method from Javascript in Android Project - PhoneGap

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I have the following Java Class

```
package com.phonegap.plugins.video;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;

public class VideoPlayer extends CordovaPlugin {
    private static final String YOU_TUBE = "youtube.com";
    private static final String ASSETS = "file:///android_asset/";

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    PluginResult.Status status = PluginResult.Status.OK;
    String result = "";
    //this.greatMethod();
    try {
        if (action.equals("playVideo")) {
            playVideo(args.getString(0));
        }
        else {
            status = PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION;
        }
        callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(status, result));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.IO_EXCEPTION));
    }
    return true;
}

private void playVideo(String url) throws IOException {
    if (url.contains("bit.ly/") || url.contains("goo.gl/") || url.contains("tinyurl.com/") || url.contains("youtu.be/")) {
        //support for google / bitly / tinyurl / youtube shortens
        URLConnection con = new URL(url).openConnection();
        con.connect();
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        //new redirected url
        url = con.getURL().toString();
        is.close();
    }

    // Create URI
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

    Intent intent = null;
    // Check to see if someone is trying to play a YouTube page.
    if (url.contains(YOU_TUBE)) {
        // If we don't do it this way you don't have the option for youtube
        uri = Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + uri.getQueryParameter("v"));
        if (isYouTubeInstalled()) {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.youtube"));
        }
    } else if(url.contains(ASSETS)) {
        // get file path in assets folder
        String filepath = url.replace(ASSETS, "");
        // get actual filename from path as command to write to internal storage doesn't like folders
        String filename = filepath.substring(filepath.lastIndexOf("/")+1, filepath.length());

        // Don't copy the file if it already exists
        File fp = new File(this.cordova.getActivity().getFilesDir() + "/" + filename);
        if (!fp.exists()) {
            this.copy(filepath, filename);
        }
        // change uri to be to the new file in internal storage
        uri = Uri.parse("file://" + this.cordova.getActivity().getFilesDir() + "/" + filename);

        //return uri; /*NEED TO RETUNRN THE URI TO THE CALLED TO GIVE THEMENEW LOCATION OF THE FILE CREATED BY THIS CLASS*/

        // Display video player
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4");
    } else {
        // Display video player
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4");
    }

    this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);

}

private void copy(String fileFrom, String fileTo) throws IOException {
    // get file to be copied from assets
    InputStream in = this.cordova.getActivity().getAssets().open(fileFrom);
    // get file where copied too, in internal storage.
    // must be MODE_WORLD_READABLE or Android can't play it
    FileOutputStream out = this.cordova.getActivity().openFileOutput(fileTo, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    in.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}

private boolean isYouTubeInstalled() {
    PackageManager pm = this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo("com.google.android.youtube", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

    public String greatMethod(){
      System.out.println("Great Method return");
      return "great";
    }
}
```

I have following in my config.xml file

```
<plugin name="VideoPlayer" value="com.phonegap.plugins.video.VideoPlayer"/>
```

I want to call say the 'greatMethod' from the javascript file. how do I do that. calling the play method like following works but calling other methods do not work and the play method is not even in the given class.

WORKS:

```
window.plugins.videoPlayer.play("file:///android_asset/www/videos/myVideo.mp4")
```

DOES NOT WORK:

```
alert(window.plugins.videoPlayer.greatMethod());
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you add greatMethod method into JavaScript PhoneGap object?

Just like following JavaScript code

```
var videoPlayer=function(){};    
videoPlayer.prototype.greatMethod = function(params, success, fail){
    return PhoneGap.exec(
            function(args){
                success(args);
            }, 
            function(args){
                fail(args);
            }, 
            'VideoPlayer', 
            'greatMethod'
    );
};
PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin('videoPlayer', new videoPlayer());
});
```

Comment: oh.am not sure my code is right, but i think you understand what do i mean